# Result I don't understand with JS object prototypes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototype

I'm trying to learn about prototypes and I tried to "re-define" console.log() so it's easier to use and write. Here's the code I used for it :

```
Object.prototype.cl = function() {
    console.log(this.valueOf())
}
```

Then, I defined a table filled with objects :

```
let arr = [
    {firstName : "John", lastName : "Doe", eyesColor : "Blue"},
    {firstName : "Johnny", lastName : "Smith", eyesColor : "Brown"},
    {firstName : "Janet", lastName : "Williams", eyesColor : "Green"},
]
```

Finally, I tried to log the values of the second line along with their names :

```
for(k in arr[1]) {
    (k + " : " + arr[1][k]).cl()
}
```

Here's what I expected to see in the console :

```
firstName : Johnny
lastName : Smith
eyesColor : Brown
```

But for some reasons, after what's just above, it also showed this :

```
cl : function() {
    console.log(this.valueOf())
}
```

Even if it's not defined at all in the array...
I saw that this function is defined as the same time of the object in the **proto** property but I don't know why it shows like this...

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Because you've directly added `cl` as a property on the prototype, it's enumerable. Because it's enumerable `for..in` goes over it. 2. Modifying native prototypes is heavily discouraged and you see one of the reasons why.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah, I've read that it's not recommended... But I really don't know how to do so I can "re-define" the console.log() function as it can take all the javascript objects as parameter (string, number, object, table, etc...). Can I achieve this with a non-native prototype?

Comment: What do you want to change? What is the goal, really? Because I really don't see how `(k + " : " + arr[1][k]).cl()` is any more clearer than `console.log(k + " : " + arr[1][k])`

Comment: Well, to me, I thought it was a good function to try this on. Also, this is a lot faster for me to go with `smth.cl()` than to wrap the thing I want to log in parenthesis and write console.log (even if I know that I can create snippets for it to be faster). Finally, if this thing is possible to do with non-native prototypes and I understand it, I think I will understand prototypes a lot better than now.

Comment: if you really must do it, look at [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)